# Split single application into multiple EAR files

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, ear, apache-tomee

We're working with a very large EJB application that is built and deployed using Maven to a TomEE server. Currently we pack everything into one EAR file, but this means even minor changes by our developers require extensive build and deploy times to try out.

Is it possible to split an EJB application into multiple EAR files (I assume it must be) and if so how can we have TomEE know which EAR files to load?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up large EAR application to smaller EAR application doesn't have anything to do with "TomEE knowing which EAR files to load" . Basically it deploys EARs that you have published to the container.

If your application is already modularized then you can think of making each/set of modules to be a EAR. Only catch is you'll have to modify the EJB look-up in the code to include module name.

If this is purely about packaging and deployment issue then it should be easy to do. If it is about highly coupled application with lot of inter-dependencies then you are standing at the point of re-organizing/re factoring your "big" application